# How to filter API response data based on particular time range using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda

I am using one lambda python function to get email logs from mailgun using mailgun log API.
Here is my function,

```
import json
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/domain/events",
                    auth=("api","key-api"))
def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)
jprint(resp.json())
```

This function gives formatted json output of email logs fetched from mailgun API

sample response from API,

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "campaigns": [],
            "delivery-status": {
                "attempt-no": 1,
                "certificate-verified": true,
                "code": 250,
                "description": "",
                "message": "OK",
                "mx-host": "host",
                "session-seconds": 1.5093050003051758,
                "tls": true
            },
            "envelope": {
                "sender": "postmaster@domain.com",
                "sending-ip": "ip",
                "targets": "id@mail.com",
                "transport": "smtp"
            },
            "event": "delivered",
            "flags": {
                "is-authenticated": true,
                "is-routed": false,
                "is-system-test": false,
                "is-test-mode": false
            },
            "id": "id",
            "log-level": "info",
            "message": {
                "attachments": [],
                "headers": {
                    "from": "NAME <noreply@name.com>",
                    "message-id": "20220223075827.de300265fad746e9@domain.com",
                    "subject": "Client due diligence information has been submitted by one of your customers.",
                    "to": "id@mail.com"
                },
                "size": 1990
            },
            "recipient": "id@mail.com",
            "recipient-domain": "domain.com",
            "storage": {
                "key": "key",
                "url": "https://storage.eu.mailgun.net/v3/domains/domain/messages/id"
            },
            "tags": [],
            "timestamp": 1645603109.434181,
            "user-variables": {}
        },
        {
            "envelope": {
                "sender": "postmaster@domain.com",
                "targets": "id@mail.com.com",
                "transport": "smtp"
            },
            "event": "accepted",
            "flags": {
                "is-authenticated": true,
                "is-test-mode": false
            },
            "id": "id",
            "log-level": "info",
            "message": {
                "headers": {
                    "from": "NAME <noreply@name.com>",
                    "message-id": "20220223075827.de300265fad746e9@domain.com",
                    "subject": "Client due diligence information has been submitted by one of your customers.",
                    "to": "id@mail.com.com"
                },
                "size": 1990
            },
            "method": "HTTP",
            "recipient": "id@mail.com",
            "recipient-domain": "domain",
            "storage": {
                "key": "key",
                "url": "https://storage.eu.mailgun.net/v3/domains/domain/messages/key"
            },
            "tags": null,
            "timestamp": 1645603107.282775,
            "user-variables": {}
        },
```

Here timestamp is not human readable

I need to setup the aws lambda python script to trigger the event to call the mailgun API periodically and send the logs to cloudwatch. I am familiar with setup but not with script.

Now I need to filter the API data only for last one hour dynamically.

From the analysis using pandas library this can be achieved but I couldn't get the proper answer to get logs for dynamic time range periodically.

I referred many docs about this but I cannot find proper answer and also python is totally new for me.

Can anyone please guide me how can i get the logs from last N time range dynamically?

Comment: Would you mind giving us a part of the response's shape?

Comment: I edited the question with sample response from mailgun API. Kindly refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to above answers, for filtering between two time and date ranges using only python, you could use datetime. Here using the same list comprehension as @Amirhossein Kiani.:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second).timestamp()
stop = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second).timestamp()

[x for x in data["items"] if start < x["timestamp"] < stop]
```

For the one hour difference, you could also use timedelta:

```
start = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).timestamp()
stop = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment will try and let you know the result

Comment: Thanks for the answer. second function is exactly what i needed. i assigned  start and stop variable as parameter with API call. It filters and fetches the last one hour logs.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#events), you can specify a [timerange](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#time-range), so your result can already be filtered using `begin` and `end` [parameters](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#query-options).

After that, you can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to reshape your json response.

Comment: Thanks for your time brother. I already referred the documents you provided. but my requirement is getting log of last one hour dynamically. I need to setup the aws lambda script to trigger the event to call the mailgun API periodically and send the logs to cloudwatch. when the API is called that should fetch the last n time logs only not older logs and not between particular time range. I am familiar with setup but not in the script. i will update my question. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Corralien said about documentation, which I personally prefer, you can use a pure python approach to reselct the last hour data using a list comprehension. In the code below, I am going to assume you named API's response as `data` which should be dictionary:

```py
from time import time
lastHour = time() - 3600
[x for x in data["items"] if x["timestamp"] > lastHour]
```

This would filter the values with a timestamp greater than the last hour(`time() - 3600`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment will try and let you know the result

Comment: If you don't mind could you guide me how can i use  this logic at above code which i mentioned in question? As i mentioned i am new to the python i cant able to understand where can i apply this logic. i am able to reproduce the logic in parameter of the API call in my code as @jonbulz mentioned. but i don't know how can i apply your solution. thanks for your time!